# How can I hang a deep box frame over drywall?

Tags: drywall, frame

I have a deep box frame that needs to be hung on drywall. The hook/hanger of the frame is 2 inches out from the wall. I don't want to cut the drywall to inset the box frame inside the wall instead. What would be something secure that sticks out 2 inches from the wall to hang the frame on? Below is the sample picture.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is "the hook of the frame?"

Comment: Are you asking for a hanger/hook whose loop end sticks out 2 inches from the wall rather than being right next to the wall?

Comment: A use for a spacer.

Comment: "Box frame" is just a frame to be hung on the wall, like a picture frame?  Can you drill holes in the frame and set the holes on pegs/screws driven into the wall?

Comment: @Armand yes you're right. The loop end sticks 2 inches from the wall.

Comment: @Solar Mike can you expand on the spacer?

Comment: @Tiger Guy it is the loop end that you hang on wall.

Comment: @huesmann I can't drill the holes in the frame.

Comment: The critical missing info here is the nature of the hook/hanger mentioned. Please revise to tell us more about that and post a photo, if possible. Details matter.

Comment: How much weight? Does it HAVE to hang from the wire or whatever at the top of the box, or could you affix the box from behind or inside? What keeps you from using a hook that's closer to the wall and a piece of picture wire or similar from that to the box? A picture of the box in question would help tremendously; that word can describe a huge variety of things.

Comment: Adding a photo in the original post. It is about 12 pounds.

Comment: @Max are you able to locate this thing laterally to get at least one anchor into a stud, or are you gonna need some other way to anchor the hangers to the wall?  And does the bottom of this thing have a similar offset between the "box" at the back and the frame as the top does?

Comment: Thank you all for engaging on this one. Certainly gives me ideas on approaching it.

Answer (score 1):

The "right" way to do it:

- Build a 4-sided box frame out of 1x planks deep enough to contain your picture,
- Add a plank to the back that can be attached to the studs in the wall to hang the whole thing, and
- Put hooks in the inside of the top of the frame to hang your picture on.

Use nice wood with paint and finish that you like.  This gives you a way to hang the picture and hides the weird gaps on the sides.  Looks a little something like this:

```
 ____________
|  ¿      ¿  |
|            |
|            |
|            |
|            |
|____________|
```

If you don't want to make something that elaborate, a simpler solution is the following:  Attach a 2x plank to wall horizontally by driving construction screws through it into wall studs (pre-drill everything).  Make sure screws are long enough to grab at least 1-1/2 inch into the studs.  Don't use drywall screws.  Add hooks to bottom of 2x and hang picture from those.

```
 ______________
|______________|
  ¿          ¿
```

You can sand and paint the the 2x (before hanging up) to make it look nicer if you want but that picture is already going to look funny standing out from the wall.

It's hard to tell how thick/wide everything is.  You could also put up a 1x or 1.25x and put screws into its front face to hook the hanging loops onto.  You may even be able to find a suitably shaped hanging shelf that you could add hooks to.  It would look finished and have provisions for hanging on the wall.  Just watch out that it's made of something that's strong enough to hold the hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda looks to me like you could just fasten a couple of wood bars vertically to the wall, a couple inches shorter than the frame is tall, and screw an L-hook to the inside face of each bar.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need screws large enough to withstand the bending forces applied. #14 wood screws embedded at least 1-1/4" into framing should do (so ~3" length). They also have heads that should work well with your triangular hanger loops. Angle them upward just slightly for best results.

[image]

<sub>[Source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mscdirect.com%2Fproduct%2Fdetails%2F67361444&psig=AOvVaw2YdyGOUtpvVCshlK1M-9fR&ust=1684336141866000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBIQjhxqFwoTCPC1-52P-v4CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE)</sub>